# Execute pantheon-files as root in elementary OS Hera

Tags: pantheon-files

I tried to execute pantheon-file as root for a programm that I intalled it. I wrote in terminal "sudo pantheon-files" and nothing. Later I searched references before to asked here, but only I found blogs, notes wrote in 2008, 2016 and finally I created and added the files scratch-openasroot.contract and folder-openasroot.contract in /usr/share/contractor without success.
How Can I open my files and directories as root?
Help me please D:
Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

You can right-click it and select "Open new window as Administrator"

Answer (score 0):

It was the first thing that I tried but doesn't show me that option unfortunately. One alternative I remembered and installed was nautilus :P.

For who will need, In terminal: "sudo apt-get install nautilus" and when finish the install "sudo nautilus"

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you are not getting the "Open New Window as Administrator" option when you right click the dock icon - works fine for me. I assume you have administrator rights?  You can try opening a terminal and typing `io.elementary.files-pkexec`.  This will open an authentication dialog where you can enter your admin password.  If it fails you should at least get some more information from the dialog or from the terminal.  Files intentionally prohibits using `sudo` as it is less secure.